# Does changing preposition change the meaning of this phrase?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, difference

I've seen both. But does changing the prepositions here change the meaning as well?

> *'someone/thing in relation **to**'* and 
>  *'someone/thing in relation **with**'?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are differences! The short answer is that you should use "to" and not "with" in this set-up.

"In relation to" most likely means what you're trying to say here. Whatever is being discussed is related or connected to another thing which provides some context.

> Where is Acton *in relation to* Westminster?

You know where Westminster is, but not Acton. You want somebody to explain where Acton is using Westminster as a reference point.

> I sent you an email *in relation to* your proposal.

My email is either in response to or contains information on your proposal. This is a slightly formal wording. It would be equally correct (and less formal) if it was worded as "I sent you an email *about* your proposal."

"In relation with" on the other hand just sounds awkward. I won't go so far as to say you'll *never* hear it, but it definitely isn't right. The confusion may be coming from the fact that "relation**s** with" is perfectly grammatical, though it means something entirely different. This talks about the interaction between two different bodies and is mostly used to describe the relationship between non-human entities, such as governments (Ex. Australia struggled to adapt to a change *in relations with* China). As noted in the comments below by @Peter, this phrasing can also be used with people as a euphemism for having an affair (Ex. He is *in relations with* his secretary).

Comment: "He is *in relations* with his secretary" is a euphemistic way of saying "he is having an affair with his secretary".

Comment: Good call, I'll add that in.

Comment: Thank you so much for the so much helpful, kind, nice, perfect answer, Emmabee! You covered, in such a kind, delicate way, the whole points I really needed explanations for. Thank you, again. Wish you a good day! :)